# AngularJS (jsFiddle included): Scope variable not updated before sent to filter

Tags: angularjs

Here's the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VSph2/274/

I'm trying to make a filter with checkboxes.

When the user clicks the checkbox, it adds the id to an array called `color_ids`. I know that's working because I print the array in the console.

However, when I try to combine that with a filter, it doesn't work. I try to pass the `$scope.color_ids` array, but it is always passing an empty array and not passing the array with values in them.

```
app.controller('IndexCtrl', ['$scope', "Product", "Color", function($scope, Product, Color) {
  ...


  // this method is triggered by a checkbox
  $scope.toggleColorFilter = function(color_id) {
    var index = $scope.color_ids.indexOf(color_id);
    if (index > -1) {
      $scope.color_ids.splice(index, 1);
    } else {
      $scope.color_ids.push(color_id);
    }
    console.log($scope.color_ids); //<-- prints the array properly with the new values.
  };

}]);
```

and a filter that isn't working:

```
app.filter('productFilter', function(){
  return function(input, color_ids) {
    console.log(color_ids); //<-- prints an empty array all the time [ ]
    return input;
  }
})
```

This is my HTML

```
<h2>Products</h2>
<div class="filters col-two" ng-controller="IndexCtrl">
  <h3>Color</h3>
    <div ng-repeat="color in colors">
      {{color.name}} <input type="checkbox" ng-model="color_ids" ng-change="toggleColorFilter(color.id)">
    </div>
  <h3>Shape</h3>
  <h3>Material</h3>
</div>
<div class="products col-ten" ng-controller="IndexCtrl">

    <div class="product" ng-repeat="product in products | productFilter:color_ids">
      <h3>
        <a href="/products/{{ product.id }}">{{ product.name }}</a>

      </h3>

      <div class="product-thumbs">
        <div class="image-wrapper" ng-repeat="product_color in product.products_colors">
          <img src="{{ product_color.color.image.url }}" width="75" height="40">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

I want the filter to eventually only show products with a color_id that exist in the `color_ids` array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three `divs` with `ng-controller="IndexCtrl"` in your `JSFiddle` example. This is the problem. Each time the Angular compiler finds ng-controller in the HTML, a new scope is created.

```
<div class="filters col-two" ng-controller="IndexCtrl">
    <h3>Color</h3>    
    <div ng-repeat="color in colors">{{color.name}}
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="color_ids" ng-change="toggleColorFilter(color.id)">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="products col-ten" ng-controller="IndexCtrl">
    <div class="product" ng-repeat="product in products | productFilter:color_ids">
        <a href="/products/{{ product.id }}">{{ product.name }}</a>    
    </div>
</div>
```

Simpliest way is to place this code in one controller and it will print 2 similiar arrays in your console:

```
<div ng-controller="IndexCtrl">
    <div class="filters col-two">
        <h3>Color</h3>    
        <div ng-repeat="color in colors">{{color.name}}
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="color_ids" ng-change="toggleColorFilter(color.id)">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="products col-ten">
        <div class="product" ng-repeat="product in products | productFilter:color_ids"> 
            <a href="/products/{{ product.id }}">{{ product.name }}</a>    
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VSph2/279/)

Comment: There are three divs with controllers in his code. Your fiddle still has two.

Comment: That is correct but both console.log are in one of them -> they work fine. I've handled this occurrence.

Answer (score 1):

The filter is applied before the color_ids is updated, you should apply the filter in the controller inside the toggle function:

```
$filter('productFilter')($scope.products, $scope.color_ids);
```

Here is the working findle (at least I think): http://jsfiddle.net/VSph2/276/
Don't forget to inject the $filter in your controller.